# Any reason behind hyphens in a GUID?

Tags: c#

Just when I generated a GUID, I found some hyphens in between the character and also at specified intervals

```
8b55fec7-c987-4e7b-abad-16e5aaea9b53
```

Is there any story behind this?

**Note:** My intention is to remove those hyphens as I am adding this GUID to a filename and our filename should only be aplhanumeric.

Comment: I think it's for readability. Although I must say it's a very strange placement of hyphens if that's the reason for them...

Comment: A GUID has several fields

Comment: See more https://stackoverflow.com/a/24484051 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/786541, which I found after asking myself a similarly worded question to the OP. Though apparently not technically valid per the spec without the hyphens, it appears to have no legitimate functional purpose for the UUID itself. See [RFC4122](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122.html) for lots of detail.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The hyphens are always placed at the same position, so you won't lose any information (or unique-ness) by removing them.

See Stack Overflow: [Why are there dashes in a .NET GUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417108/why-are-there-dashes-in-a-net-guid) for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 9):

Long sequences are very hard to parse for humans, hence the hyphens. But [GUID itself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) is just a number, so you can drop them.